# issue with openSSH

Tags: ssh

I am having wierd issue with openSSH connecting to
remote server.
I can connect it with userID and password, 
but when I use the public key authentication, it shows the following lines 
in the putty.log and quits.

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2011.06.02 13:44:04 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Using username "******".

Authenticating with public key "comment-----"
Last login: Wed Jun  1 17:27:13 2011 from ****.com
```

ANd then the putty quits.

I went thru different posts, where they talk about shell cmd and other stuffs and I am lost now.

Both the machines are running in windows with openssh.
Can anybody guide me from where to start now.

ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: Enabling debugging in your putty might be a place to start.  If you are able to connect from that same machine using a password without the key enabled I would suspect something in your authorized_keys file on the destination machine, so you might want to look there.

Comment: You mention you are running OpenSSH on Windows.  How exactly are you doing that.  Via Cygwin, CopSSH, or something else?  If you have a full Cygwin on the server, can you use ssh on the server to make a connection to the localhost?  Have you considered at least temporarily installing Cygwin on a client, and using that to attempt to connect?

Answer (score 2):

Puttygen generates an SSH2 aka [Tectia or ssh.com](http://www.tectia.com/en/Solutions/Secure/Tectia_Client_and_Server.iw3) public key when you use the 'Save public key' button, not a OpenSSH key. Different servers need a different type of key.

In puttygen load your private key file, and copy the line that looks like this `ssh-rsa AAAAB3...` from the dialog box labeled **'Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file'**.

[image: Puttygen public key]

OpenSSH Public key

```
ssh-rsa AAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIBQ2Si6NjLR40YTI+9Z/TTBSYUykO1RjAX3GA2Zs15v7wiBVz3JoeLXFAmXRApdWCHCsmZIAjiX+qC0Ks1MY4suphDQv1ZfJE1xmhRwqr7h4f+/i0QmGI05lr/yJqwSashUIF4YWqgC14ov57VtaiCp//GTU29exME/JX3FzzxVmw== rsa-key-20110602
```

ssh.com Public key

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20110602"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIBQ2Si6NjLR40YTI+9Z/TTBSYUykO1RjAX3GA2Z
s15v7wiBVz3JoeLXFAmXRApdWCHCsmZIAjiX+qC0Ks1MY4suphDQv1ZfJE1xmhRw
qr7h4f+/i0QmGI05lr/yJqwSashUIF4YWqgC14ov57VtaiCp//GTU29exME/JX3F
zzxVmw==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

Comment: yes it looks the same ....it starts with ssh-rsa AAA- - - - - -...thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your public and/or private key may be corrupt.

Are you saying the server uses Windows too? In that case I don't know where to look for the keys, but usually they're called `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. What is in `id_rsa.pub`? And what is in the file `authorized_keys`?

Comment: @Eduardo Ivanec
public/private were generated by puttygen and public key was pasted on the authorized_keys in the server and private file with .pkk extension was supplied from putty. If there was sth wrong with keys then, wouldnt it be saying , key invalid or refused.....

Comment: @user54898, puttygen generates a public key in a format that isn't appropriate for OpenSSH if you click the button.

Comment: i mean i copy pasted to authorized_keys file. it was in correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `authorized_keys` file on the server - the server may be forcing a command based on the key you're using to authenticate, which could explain the different behaviour when logging in with a public key instead of a password.

To check this look for a `command=` string somewhere in the file.

Comment: I did a search but I could not find anything.....

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is the permissions on the authorized_keys file itself.  As you are on windows, I am unfamiliar with that side, but in the *nix world, if the ssh daemon sees that your authorized_keys file is world readable it will refuse to honor it.

Comment: Can you tell me how to see the log files in windows except putty.log(Which doesnot give enough info),